# HttpClient Request works windows , but not working in my server Ubuntu

Tags: c#, ubuntu, httpclient

I am new in asp.net core. this code works on windows not on my ubuntu server.
HttpClient Works in Windows , not in Ubuntu.

```
  public async  Task<JsonResult>  PostPaid ( [FromBody]  object  ob)
{
    String rep = "";
    User d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(ob.ToString());
    try
    {

        var vm = new { username = d.Login, password = d.Pwd };

        {
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
            };

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
            //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri(d.MyUrl),
                Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
            httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage result = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            rep = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex.ToString());
    }
    return Json(rep);
}
```

I would like an example which works in ubuntu please.

error message : "One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)"

"System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)\n ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()\n   at SmsWeb.Controllers.UserController.PostPaid(Object ob) in E:\Nouveau dossier\Projetdeveloppement\Projets\webasp\Sms - Copie (40)-bon-anomalie-POstPaid\WebMat\Controllers\UserController.cs:line 765"

Comment: Usually this type failure is due to HTTPS (secure) and the TLS authentication is failing.  Try add to the beginning of the code above the static metod : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 |
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;                       
               HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Any exceptions? If yes, which one, please include the full exception message, inner exception and stacktrace.

Comment: @mastermelo don't get hung up on ServicePointManager, you don't use it with HttpClient in .NET Core. Especially since you haven't mentioned the error yet.

Comment: exception :"One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)"

Comment: I can't say what your problem is exactly but here are two things to improve: 1. Make the action `async` and `await` your tasks instead of using `.Result`. 2. Use another overload of StringContent: `Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

Comment: I transformed , i get this error        "System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.\n

Comment: Don't create `HttpClient` per use. Use single instance for all requests instead. Also read this [Using objects that implement IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects). You're ignoring `IDisposable` usage which isn't good. Also use `async/await` instead of `.Result` - [Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async). Also for ASP.NET Core learn about `AsyncActionResult`.

Comment: i tried  this , that's works only windows , not ubuntu . 
on windows the response is very fast, but on ubuntu the response is slow until it is completely canceled and an exception is raised . 
I'm starting to be desperate, I've been shooting for 4 days